# WordPress: Media Library missing images

Tags: database, wordpress, media-library

I'm starting to think there's a whole lot more to the media library than what I know. I just migrated a gigantic site. It has several thousand images and various insanities that made the export some 20 gigs. So I had to do a lot of manual moving, special tricks and all that.

A side effect is that the media library seems to have just given up, after about 20 items. I ran force regenerate thumbnails and it eventually claimed 100% success, yet still, the images aren't in the media library.

In the database, they are all in the `wp_posts` table as attachments, which is expected. In the `wp_postmeta` they have the entries for `_wp_attached_file` and `_wp_attachment_metadata` and the data in there looks legitimate.

Is there some other connection in the database I don't know if that would explain how they can be in the file system, in the database, and yet not in the media library?

*UPDATE*

It should be noted that in list view, it does show all images. Just not for the main thumbnail view, which is the one the client prefers. All caches have been cleared, by the way.

Answer (score 0):

I have used the plugin Media from FTP to solve this problem--it will register the images. Just having them in the database doesn't mean they're in the WP library and the plugin will solve the problem.

I've also had good luck overcoming this problem by using WP export and import. It has problems with large volume, but you can move a few at a time using a date window.